# Should training and test set in ridge regression have the same size?

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I'm trying to perform a ridge regression, so I started trying to split the data into two subsamples, I would like to mention that my data is imputed, so there are no `NA` values in (I double check with function `vis_miss`):

```
# Sample data from my current data set
loc <- sample(1:nrow(main_df_nipals_imputed_1),
              round(nrow(main_df_nipals_imputed_1) * 0.9))
# Divide data set into training and testing set
# Training
read_training <- main_df_nipals_imputed_1[loc, ]
# Test
read_test <- main_df_nipals_imputed_1[-loc, ]
```

After this, I apply ridge regression

```
ridge <- cv.glmnet(x = read_training, 
                   y = read_test, 
                   type.measure = "mse", 
                   alpha = 0, 
                   family = "gaussian", 
                   nlambda = 200)
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
Error in glmnet(read_training, read_test) : 
  number of observations in y (10) not equal to the number of rows of x (94)
```

I think that the error is pretty intuitive, so I decided to check the dimensions of my data:

```
> dim(read_test)
[1] 10 84
> dim(read_training)
[1] 94 84
```

I think that at this point, the output should be, maybe I`m wrong:

```
> dim(read_test)
[1] 10 84
> dim(read_training)
[1] 84 94
```

So far, the only answer to explain this is that I have missing values, which is not the case.

So, I checked if the `training` and `test` sets must be the same size, however, that is not the case, I think.

Before sharing my data, I would like to center this post in the context of what is incorrect in the data preparation for the ridge regression.

Question:

- How can we solve this issue?
- Is it mandatory that both data sets have the same size?

Comment: In `cv.glmnet` your `x` is your predictor/explanatory/independent variables, and your `y` is your response/outcome/dependent variable. Each row of `x` should be all the observations corresponding to a single `y` value, so the number of rows of `x` should be equal to the length of the **vector** `y`. They are not training and test. Generally test data is smaller than training data, but there are no strict requirements.

Comment: Also, `cv.glmnet`, as the first sentence of the `?cv.glmnet` help page states, *"Does k-fold cross-validation"*. You don't give it separate test and train sets, it uses the k-fold approach to sample a default of `nfolds = 10` "folds" of train/test pairs. I'd strongly suggest working through some examples. There are several at the bottom of the help page. Or see corresponding sections in the free Introduction to Statistical Learning with R book.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, help me a lot, I will try to make some modification to my current approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what the `x` and `y` parameters represent. Per the [documentation](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/cv.glmnet.html), `x` is a matrix of predictor features from a data set, and `y` is are the corresponding prediction targets *from the same dataset*. The number of observations in `x` and `y` must therefore be the same. The function then performs k-fold cross validation with that dataset to tune the elastic net mixing constants.

As you've done, you'd typically split the whole dataset into training and test partitions. You'd supply the training partition to the `cv.glmnet` function to perform hyperparameter tuning. Once you have the best hyperparameters, you could retrain the model in the full training set using the optimal hyperparameters. You would then use the test partition to assess that model's ability to generalize to unseen data.

To answer your first question more directly, the argument to `x` should include the subset of columns in `read_training` that are used as predictive features in your model. The argument to `y` should be the prediction target column.

To answer your second question, no, the training and test datasets do not need to have the same number of observations, but they should have the same set of features.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I need to reformulate my idea for sure